# How to resolve performance issue using ng-repeat directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

I see some performance issue using socket.io with ng-repeat angular directive, i am receiving alot of data from backend that slow down the application so while receiving data i would not be able to click on anything. What would be the best way to deal with large list using ng-repeat, lets assume 1000 messages per minute ?

ctrl.js

```
  $scope.event = [];
  socket.on('ditConsumer', function(data) {
              var obj = {
                  file: $scope.filename,
                  data: data
              }
              $scope.event.push(data);
          }
```

main.html

```
<ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="message in event track by $index" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span><strong>Log:</strong></span><span>{{message}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do  a web search on this topic and will find lots of information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first of all use some kind of *message id* in `ng-repeat="message in event track by $index"` instead of $index which is rendered each ng-repeat digest. See http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/

second - you can limit visual items with limitTo filter:

```
ng-repeat="message in event track by message.id | limitTo:100"
```

hidden items will be still searchable and recoverable by other filters but not rendered in HTML

Comment: data has only message string from the server, How i will create id if its not part of data.

Comment: just change array of string to array of objects: {id: ID, value: MESSAGE}, you can do it in your service as: $scope.event.push(data.map((val, key) => {id:key, value:val})); then in HTML: ng-repeat="message in event track message.id" and print {{ message.value }} (or, alternatively add ng-bind="message.value" insted

Comment: you mean change $scope.event = [] to $scope.event [{id:key, value:val}]

Comment: my mistake, I thought data is array of messages, I see that it is a single message received with WS or something alike... Currently $scope.event is an array of your messages, each item is a string - message, we want to have each item as object, so push it as object: $scope.event.push({id:$scope.event.length, value:data}); (again, I assume that data received is STRING message)

Comment: Got it, Do you think its a good solution to resolve performance issue mentioned in question ?

Comment: yes, it should improve performance, can you measure time in both cases in some way?

Comment: Thanks for the help i was able to rendered data for ng-repeat so i can use message.id. Let me see if it improve performance.